BluetoothAdapter sometimes not emiting STATE_TURNING_OFF
I am developing an Android application that heavily relies on Bluetooth connectivity. I've implemented a BroadcastReceiver to listen for changes in the Bluetooth state, specifically monitoring the BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED intent to detect when the Bluetooth adapter is turning off or has turned off.
Here is a snippet of my code:
private final BroadcastReceiver bluetoothStateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED.equals(action)) {
            final int state = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE, BluetoothAdapter.ERROR);
            switch (state) {
                case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_OFF:
                    // Handle Bluetooth turning off
                    handleBluetoothTurningOff();
                    break;
                case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_OFF:
                    // Handle Bluetooth being off
                    handleBluetoothOff();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
};

I have captured logs with ADB to ensure that the device is not emitting the desired Intent:
08-12 14:28:10.369  5868  5868 D BluetoothGatt: connect() - device: 00091F_A, auto: false
08-12 14:28:10.370  5868  5868 D BluetoothGatt: registerApp()
08-12 14:28:10.371  5868  5868 D BluetoothGatt: registerApp() - UUID=fc7486f2-6fe9-4101-a439-d6f0498067d1
08-12 14:28:10.383  5868  5901 D BluetoothGatt: onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=5
08-12 14:28:15.421  5868  5901 D BluetoothGatt: onClientConnectionState() - status=133 clientIf=5 device=00091F_A
08-12 14:28:15.444  5868  5901 D BluetoothGatt: close()
08-12 14:28:15.451  5868  5901 D BluetoothGatt: unregisterApp() - mClientIf=5
08-12 14:28:21.162 13313 13438 D BluetoothAdapter: onBluetoothServiceDown
08-12 14:28:21.163  1624  1639 D BluetoothAdapter: onBluetoothServiceDown
08-12 14:28:21.163  2970  2990 D BluetoothAdapter: onBluetoothServiceDown
08-12 14:28:21.163  5868 16206 D BluetoothAdapter: onBluetoothServiceDown
08-12 14:28:21.164  1270  1431 D BluetoothAdapter: onBluetoothServiceDown
08-12 14:28:21.164  3258  6357 D BluetoothAdapter: onBluetoothServiceDown
08-12 14:28:21.165  1957  3863 D BluetoothAdapter: onBluetoothServiceDown
08-12 14:28:21.165  1605  5864 D BluetoothAdapter: onBluetoothServiceDown
08-12 14:28:21.166 13001 13024 D BluetoothAdapter: onBluetoothServiceDown
08-12 14:28:21.166 13026 16208 D BluetoothAdapter: onBluetoothServiceDown
08-12 14:28:21.185 13313 13438 D BluetoothAdapter: onBluetoothServiceDown
08-12 14:28:21.186  1605  5864 D BluetoothAdapter: onBluetoothServiceDown
08-12 14:28:21.186  1270  1431 D BluetoothAdapter: onBluetoothServiceDown
08-12 14:28:21.186  5868 16206 D BluetoothAdapter: onBluetoothServiceDown
08-12 14:28:21.186  2970  2990 D BluetoothAdapter: onBluetoothServiceDown
08-12 14:28:21.186  3258  6357 D BluetoothAdapter: onBluetoothServiceDown
08-12 14:28:21.186 13001 13024 D BluetoothAdapter: onBluetoothServiceDown
08-12 14:28:21.186  1624  1639 D BluetoothAdapter: onBluetoothServiceDown
08-12 14:28:21.187 13026 16208 D BluetoothAdapter: onBluetoothServiceDown
08-12 14:28:21.187  1957  4130 D BluetoothAdapter: onBluetoothServiceDown
08-12 14:28:21.188  1957  4556 I BluetoothAdapter: BluetoothAdapter() : com.google.android.gms
08-12 14:28:21.212  1957  4790 I BluetoothAdapter: STATE_OFF=10
08-12 14:28:21.215  1957  4790 I BluetoothAdapter: STATE_OFF=10
08-12 14:28:21.215  1957  4790 D BluetoothLeScanner: stop scan is not allowed as BT is off
08-12 14:28:21.217  1270  1270 I BluetoothAdapter: STATE_OFF=10
08-12 14:28:21.228  1270  1270 I BluetoothAdapter: STATE_OFF=10
08-12 14:28:21.244  1270  1270 I BluetoothAdapter: STATE_OFF=10
08-12 14:28:21.245  1270  1270 I BluetoothAdapter: STATE_OFF=10
08-12 14:28:21.246  5868  5868 I BluetoothAdapter: STATE_OFF=10
08-12 14:28:21.246  5868  5868 D BluetoothLeScanner: stop scan is not allowed as BT is off
08-12 14:28:21.253  5868  5868 I BluetoothAdapter: STATE_OFF=10
08-12 14:28:21.253  5868  5868 D BluetoothLeScanner: stop scan is not allowed as BT is off
08-12 14:28:21.253  5868  5868 I BluetoothAdapter: STATE_OFF=10
08-12 14:28:21.253  5868  5868 D BluetoothLeScanner: stop scan is not allowed as BT is off
08-12 14:28:21.253  5868  5868 I BluetoothAdapter: STATE_OFF=10
08-12 14:28:21.253  5868  5868 D BluetoothLeScanner: stop scan is not allowed as BT is off
08-12 14:28:21.253  5868  5868 I BluetoothAdapter: STATE_OFF=10
08-12 14:28:21.253  5868  5868 D BluetoothLeScanner: stop scan is not allowed as BT is off
08-12 14:28:21.253  5868  5868 I BluetoothAdapter: STATE_OFF=10
08-12 14:28:21.253  5868  5868 D BluetoothLeScanner: stop scan is not allowed as BT is off
08-12 14:28:21.267  1957  4790 I BluetoothAdapter: STATE_OFF=10
08-12 14:28:21.408  1957  1957 I BluetoothAdapter: BluetoothAdapter() : com.google.android.gms
08-12 14:28:22.006 16228 16228 I BluetoothAdapter: BluetoothAdapter() : com.android.bluetooth
08-12 14:28:22.204 13313 13832 D BluetoothAdapter: onBluetoothServiceUp: android.bluetooth.IBluetooth$Stub$Proxy@687270d
08-12 14:28:22.204  1605  5864 D BluetoothAdapter: onBluetoothServiceUp: android.bluetooth.IBluetooth$Stub$Proxy@c42db05
08-12 14:28:22.204  2970  8098 D BluetoothAdapter: onBluetoothServiceUp: android.bluetooth.IBluetooth$Stub$Proxy@9f044fb
08-12 14:28:22.205  5868 15214 D BluetoothAdapter: onBluetoothServiceUp: android.bluetooth.IBluetooth$Stub$Proxy@c313804
08-12 14:28:22.205  1270  1431 D BluetoothAdapter: onBluetoothServiceUp: android.bluetooth.IBluetooth$Stub$Proxy@75b5a99
08-12 14:28:22.205  1624  1639 D BluetoothAdapter: onBluetoothServiceUp: android.bluetooth.IBluetooth$Stub$Proxy@8eff7df
08-12 14:28:22.206  1957  3863 D BluetoothAdapter: onBluetoothServiceUp: android.bluetooth.IBluetooth$Stub$Proxy@5e00d03
08-12 14:28:22.206  3258  4734 D BluetoothAdapter: onBluetoothServiceUp: android.bluetooth.IBluetooth$Stub$Proxy@5004e05
08-12 14:28:22.208 13001 13024 D BluetoothAdapter: onBluetoothServiceUp: android.bluetooth.IBluetooth$Stub$Proxy@e28ae0a
08-12 14:28:22.208 13026 13306 D BluetoothAdapter: onBluetoothServiceUp: android.bluetooth.IBluetooth$Stub$Proxy@3de93fe
08-12 14:28:22.209 16228 16240 D BluetoothAdapter: onBluetoothServiceUp: com.android.bluetooth.btservice.AdapterService$AdapterServiceBinder@dd932f7
08-12 14:28:22.246  1270  1270 I BluetoothAdapter: STATE_OFF=14
08-12 14:28:22.274  1957  4790 I BluetoothAdapter: STATE_OFF=14
08-12 14:28:22.731 13026 13026 I BluetoothAdapter: STATE_OFF=14
08-12 14:28:22.731 13026 13026 I BluetoothAdapter: STATE_OFF=14
08-12 14:28:22.731 13026 13026 I BluetoothAdapter: STATE_OFF=14
08-12 14:28:22.731 13026 13026 I BluetoothAdapter: STATE_OFF=14
08-12 14:28:22.735  1624  1773 I BluetoothAdapter: STATE_OFF=14
08-12 14:28:22.735  1624  1773 I BluetoothAdapter: STATE_OFF=14
08-12 14:28:22.735  1624  1773 I BluetoothAdapter: STATE_OFF=14
08-12 14:28:22.735  1624  1773 I BluetoothAdapter: STATE_OFF=14
08-12 14:28:22.739  1624  1773 I BluetoothAdapter: STATE_OFF=14
08-12 14:28:22.740  1624  1773 I BluetoothAdapter: STATE_OFF=14
08-12 14:28:22.740  1624  1773 I BluetoothAdapter: STATE_OFF=14
08-12 14:28:22.740  1624  1773 I BluetoothAdapter: STATE_OFF=14
08-12 14:28:22.743  1624  1773 I BluetoothAdapter: STATE_OFF=14
08-12 14:28:22.743  1624  1773 I BluetoothAdapter: STATE_OFF=14
08-12 14:28:22.743  1624  1773 I BluetoothAdapter: STATE_OFF=14
08-12 14:28:22.743  1624  1773 I BluetoothAdapter: STATE_OFF=14
08-12 14:28:22.746  1624  1773 I BluetoothAdapter: STATE_OFF=14
08-12 14:28:22.746  1624  1773 I BluetoothAdapter: STATE_OFF=14
08-12 14:28:22.746  1624  1773 I BluetoothAdapter: STATE_OFF=14
08-12 14:28:22.746  1624  1773 I BluetoothAdapter: STATE_OFF=14
08-12 14:28:22.747  1624  1773 I BluetoothAdapter: STATE_OFF=14
08-12 14:28:22.747  1624  1773 I BluetoothAdapter: STATE_OFF=14
08-12 14:28:22.747  1624  1773 I BluetoothAdapter: STATE_OFF=14
08-12 14:28:22.747  1624  1773 I BluetoothAdapter: STATE_OFF=14
08-12 14:28:22.748  1624  1773 I BluetoothAdapter: STATE_OFF=14
08-12 14:28:22.748  1624  1773 I BluetoothAdapter: STATE_OFF=14
08-12 14:28:22.748  1624  1773 I BluetoothAdapter: STATE_OFF=14
08-12 14:28:22.748  1624  1773 I BluetoothAdapter: STATE_OFF=14
08-12 14:28:22.749 13026 13026 I BluetoothAdapter: STATE_OFF=14
08-12 14:28:22.749 13026 13026 I BluetoothAdapter: STATE_OFF=14
08-12 14:28:22.749 13026 13026 I BluetoothAdapter: STATE_OFF=14
08-12 14:28:22.749 13026 13026 I BluetoothAdapter: STATE_OFF=14
08-12 14:28:22.755 13026 13026 I BluetoothAdapter: STATE_OFF=14
08-12 14:28:22.755 13026 13026 I BluetoothAdapter: STATE_OFF=14
08-12 14:28:22.756 13026 13026 I BluetoothAdapter: STATE_OFF=14
08-12 14:28:22.756 13026 13026 I BluetoothAdapter: STATE_OFF=14
08-12 14:28:22.765 13026 13026 I BluetoothAdapter: STATE_OFF=14
08-12 14:28:22.765 13026 13026 I BluetoothAdapter: STATE_OFF=14
08-12 14:28:22.765 13026 13026 I BluetoothAdapter: STATE_OFF=14
08-12 14:28:22.765 13026 13026 I BluetoothAdapter: STATE_OFF=14
08-12 14:28:22.774 13026 13026 I BluetoothAdapter: STATE_BLE_ON
08-12 14:28:22.775 13026 13026 I BluetoothAdapter: STATE_BLE_ON
08-12 14:28:22.775 13026 13026 I BluetoothAdapter: STATE_BLE_ON
08-12 14:28:22.775 13026 13026 I BluetoothAdapter: STATE_BLE_ON
08-12 14:28:22.782  1270  1270 I BluetoothAdapter: STATE_BLE_ON
08-12 14:28:22.782  1270  1270 I BluetoothAdapter: appoCount is = 1
08-12 14:28:22.783  1270  1270 I BluetoothAdapter: STATE_BLE_ON
08-12 14:28:22.783  1270  1270 I BluetoothAdapter: appoCount is = 1 G/S = 1/0
08-12 14:28:22.787 13026 13026 I BluetoothAdapter: STATE_TURNING_ON
08-12 14:28:22.788 13026 13026 I BluetoothAdapter: STATE_TURNING_ON
08-12 14:28:22.789 13026 13026 I BluetoothAdapter: STATE_TURNING_ON
08-12 14:28:22.789 13026 13026 I BluetoothAdapter: STATE_TURNING_ON
08-12 14:28:22.797  1270  1270 I BluetoothAdapter: STATE_TURNING_ON
08-12 14:28:22.818  1270  1270 I BluetoothAdapter: STATE_TURNING_ON
08-12 14:28:22.886 16228 16228 I BluetoothAdapter: BluetoothAdapter() : com.android.bluetooth
08-12 14:28:23.041 16228 16228 I BluetoothAdapter: BluetoothAdapter() : com.android.bluetooth
08-12 14:28:23.058 16228 16228 D BluetoothAdapter: listenUsingL2capOn: set assigned channel to 4097
08-12 14:28:23.296  1957  4790 I BluetoothAdapter: STATE_TURNING_ON

In most cases, this setup works as expected. However, I've noticed that sometimes the BluetoothAdapter does not emit the STATE_TURNING_OFF intent at all. This leads to situations where my app is not notified that Bluetooth is turning off, and therefore, it cannot react appropriately (e.g., by cleaning up resources or notifying the user).
This behavior seems inconsistent, and I haven't been able to identify a pattern or specific conditions under which the intent is not emitted.
My Questions:

Why does the BluetoothAdapter sometimes fail to emit the STATE_TURNING_OFF intent?
Are there known circumstances or limitations that could prevent this intent from being broadcasted?
What are the best practices to ensure my app reliably detects when the Bluetooth adapter is turning off?
I have seen that the method onBluetoothServiceDown from a private static callback inside BluetoothAdapter is being called, is it a good idea to access this private callback? (Through reflection, for example)

I've considered adding a fallback mechanism, such as periodically polling the BluetoothAdapter state, but I'm looking for a better understanding of the root cause and if there's a more robust solution.
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

One question per question please; else the scope becomes too broad. Also requesting opinion-based answers is off-topic. When reducing it the main problem, this would permit to identify a correct answer.

Good call Martin, I guess the main question would be: Why does the BluetoothAdapter sometimes fail to emit the STATE_TURNING_OFF intent?

I believe that this is happening due to the very rapid/temporary nature of this state, which may be extremely brief or skipped altogether, depending on the hardware or the Android Bluetooth stack implementation. I suggest testing your code across different hardware to see if the behaviour matches, but in any case my recommendation is to refrain from using this approach given that it seems that you are doing things correctly yet it is still not working as expected. Instead, consider using the STATE_OFF intent instead of STATE_TURNING_OFF given that it is more reliable, or use your fallback mechanism of checking the BluetoothAdapter state.
Below are some links to how others have got this working in the past in case you haven't seen them already:-

Detecting state changes made to the BluetoothAdapter
Android broadcast receiver Bluetooth events catching

